# Boolean variable .toString() Function Displays [Object Object]

Tags: javascript, angularjs

I have a C# bool method that is called and executed on the client through AngularJS. The method works without any error as I have confirmed but the string result (`result.toString()`) of the execution (true or false) displays `[Object Object]` instead. Below is the script function;

```
vm.isActiveCustomer = function(sp) {
     abp.ui.setBusy();
     var result = sessionService.isActiveCustomer({
         id: sp.id
     }).success(function() {
         abp.notify.info(result.toString());
     }).finally(function() {
         abp.ui.clearBusy();
     });        
}
```

It looks simple but I can't get it to display what I want. Please Help.

Comment: try var result = JSON.stringify(result).  Then print the result var.

Comment: Maybe result is an array, what's show in console.log(result); ?

Comment: @user2263572 Thank for your response. I tried it and it gave me this: `{"$$state":"status":0}`. Again, not what I need.

Comment: whoa, what? that's not valid json at all, you couldn't have possibly gotten that.

Comment: `{$$state: Object}
$$state
:
Object
status
:
1
value
:
Object
config
:
Object
data
:
false
headers
:
(d)
status
:
200
statusText
:
"OK"
__proto__
:
Object
__proto__
:
Object
__proto__
:
Object`      I got that when i ran console.log(result)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You are missing an argument to the success callback. `result` is a likely a promise and handling an async request. You'll have to keep the flow and keep it async.

Comment: Could you throw more light to what you just said? Actually the method it's executing is an async method. But I don't see how it isn't yielding the desired result.

Comment: @KaceyEzerioha http://stackoverflow.com/questions/14220321/how-do-i-return-the-response-from-an-asynchronous-call

Comment: Very long answer it has got and it took me a while to understand it. Thanks for pointing me to it.